# How can I make the turtle go to a variable point?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

**Goal:**

Make my turtle go to a point, selected by the user.

**Something like that:**

```
ranpoint = input()
turtle(go, randpoint)
```

Comment: In what format would the user enter a point?

Comment: coordinate (50,50)

Answer (score 1):

this code takes input in form (x,y) from user, splits it by ',', deletes the parantheses, casts them to float and sends them to function.

```
  d=input()
  a=d.split(',')[0]
  b=d.split(',')[1]
  turtle.setpos(float(a[1:]),float(b[:-1]))
```

Comment: How about `a, b = d.split(',')` instead of doing the same split twice?